# Textmate Regex: Find word based on a pattern that only exists in declaration

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, textmate

Is it possible to have a regex expression match with a pattern that finds a word and then also matches with any other occurrences of that word?

To be more explicit, lets say I have some language that declares variables with a `#` like `#varName`

I also have the regex expression `(?<=#)\w*` to locate such words.

However, in another part of my code I use `varName` without the `#` and thus cannot identify it using the same method.

So my question is, can I write one regex expression to locate `varName` in both instances?

My intention is to use this to write a syntax definition for sublime-text, so I am using textmate's regex syntax.

Comment: You need to **capture** it: `(?<=#)(\w*)`

Comment: @jan not enough you will only match the first occurance #varName.  + i think @elias knows the capturing if he knows positive lookbehind :). actually i was thinking of sth like `(?:(?<=#)(\w+).*?(\1))|(?<=#)(\w+)` https://regex101.com/r/dT4pT9/1. but it would obviously match only  2 occurances. I tried recurence also but cant quite get it i'm getting headache now haha. Do it in 2 steps in very easy, but in a single regex its a good challenge!